# Checkbox that make multiple pictures visible

Tags: javascript, html

I am quite new to js and html and have some problems with a task. I want to create a "checkbox" that will make some pictures visible. For example I have 5 pictures. On each picture there is a male or female. Now i want to make all female picures visible if someone check the "female checkbox".
So far I have a jq solution and tried to convert it to js but failed. Do anyone know how to solve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Event handler for checkboxes with name="gender"
    $(':checkbox[name=gender]').on('change',function() {
        $('img[data-gender=' + this.value + ']').css('visibility', this.checked ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
    });
    //Event handler for checkboxes with name="visibility"
    $(':checkbox[name=visibility]').on('change', function() {
        $('img[src*=' + this.value + ']').css('visibility',this.checked ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
    });
});
```

```css
.myimage {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='Humans'>

    <label for="gender1">male</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="gender1" value="male" /><br/>

    <label for="gender2">female</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="gender2" value="female" /><br/>

    <label for="visibility1">Person1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="visibility" id="visibility1" value="Person1" /><br/>

    <label for="visibility2">Person2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="visibility" id="visibility2" value="Person2" /><br/>

    <label for="visibility3">Person3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="visibility" id="visibility3" value="Person3" /><br/>

    <label for="visibility4">Person4</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="visibility" id="visibility4" value="Person4" /><br/>

    <label for="visibility5">Person5</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="visibility" id="visibility5" value="Person5" /><br/>

    <img src='/home/Person1.png' data-gender="male" class="myimage"/> <!--male-->
    <img src='/home/Person2.png' data-gender="female" class="myimage"/> <!--female-->
    <img src='/home/Person3.png' data-gender="female" class="myimage"/> <!--female-->
    <img src='/home/Person4.png' data-gender="male" class="myimage"/> <!--male-->
    <img src='/home/Person5.png' data-gender="female" class="myimage"/> <!--female-->
    </div>
```

I tried to edit this by changing the function to

```js
  function checkgender(type) {
     for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) { 
  var el = document.getElementById(i);
  if(type==1){
   if (el.data-gender=="male") {
    el.style.visibility="visible";
    }
   else {
    el.style.visibility="hidden";
    }
   }
  else if(type==2){
   if (el.data-gender=="female") {
    el.style.visibility="visible";
    }
   else {
    el.style.visibility="hidden";
    }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<label for="gender1">male</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="gender1" value="male" onChange="checkgender(1);" /><br/>

    <label for="gender2">female</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="gender2" value="female" onChange="checkgender(2);"/><br/>

    <label for="visibility1">Person1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="visibility" id="visibility1" value="Person1" /><br/>

    <label for="visibility2">Person2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="visibility" id="visibility2" value="Person2" /><br/>

    <label for="visibility3">Person3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="visibility" id="visibility3" value="Person3" /><br/>

    <label for="visibility4">Person4</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="visibility" id="visibility4" value="Person4" /><br/>

    <label for="visibility5">Person5</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="visibility" id="visibility5" value="Person5" /><br/>

    <img id='1' src='/home/Person1.png' data-gender="male" class="myimage"  style='visibility:hidden'/> <!--male-->
    <img id='2' src='/home/Person2.png' data-gender="female" class="myimage" style='visibility:hidden'/> <!--female-->
    <img id='3' src='/home/Person3.png' data-gender="female" class="myimage"  style='visibility:hidden'/> <!--female-->
    <img id='4' src='/home/Person4.png' data-gender="male" class="myimage" style='visibility:hidden'/> <!--male-->
    <img id='5' src='/home/Person5.png' data-gender="female" class="myimage"  style='visibility:hidden'/> <!--female-->
    </div>
```

But it didn't work. It would be great if someone could tell me how to fix it.

Comment: The pictures cannot load, but the check boxes seem to be working for me.

Comment: Are you refering to the jq one or the js one? The jq is the first one and it is ok. The second one is my attempt to convert it into js (no jq) and it do not work.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the question properly, you're right, only the first one works, is the HTML code the same for both?

Comment: Well, i posted the HTML code. It is slightly different.

Comment: OK, think I've found the problem, looked directly at the second example source, you haven't put your JS code in a function so you cannot call it from the HTML.

Comment: I fixed that but it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that I would make this an official answer, after making the code into a function, the problem is now that you have requested the `data-gender` attribute in the wrong manner (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes). You can fix this by replacing `if (el.data-gender==` with `if (el.dataset.gender==`. Hope this helps, if it does can you accept this please!

Comment: And what should i request? I am new to this stuff so i am not sure how to do this.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, you're requesting the right thing but in the wrong way...see my answer.